# Проблема с загрузкой аудио в ВК

Tags: java, android, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, аудио

Необходимо загрузить аудио файл в вк. Для этого я использую Kate VK API. Выглядит это так:

```
public void uploadAudioToWall(String filePath, String url){
    try {
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity albumArtEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=*****");
        albumArtEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(filePath)));

        httpPost.setEntity(albumArtEntity);
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        JSONObject photoObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        Log.e("FILE", filePath);
        Log.e("NEW URI", url);
        Log.e("res", photoObject.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вызываю функцию так:

```
String upurl = api.getAudioUploadServer();
uploadAudioToWall(path, upurl);
```

В переменной path хранится путь к файлу 
(например, "/storage/emulated/0/Rec/22-41-39_21-3-2015.mp3")

В ответ я получаю следующее:

```
{
  "redirect":"http:\/\/vk.com\/audio.php?act=done_add&mid=120146182&aid=0&gid=0&server=611229&audio=%7B%22error%22%3A-2%7D&hash=7343021a24966d4e0fe12e485d53aa3d",
  "server":611229,
  "audio":"%7B%22error%22%3A-2%7D",
  "hash":"7343021a24966d4e0fe12e485d53aa3d"
}
```

Почему же он мне возвращает "audio":"%7B%22error%22%3A-2%7D"? Помогите найти ошибку.

P.S. Токен есть, приложение включено и получает доступ к аудиозаписям.

Comment: Строка `httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=*****");` разве не лишняя?

Comment: Вы обращались в поддержку?

Comment: да, обращался, но ответа так и не слышно

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос очень простой:

```
"audio":"%7B%22error%22%3A-2%7D"
```

расшифровывается в error: -2. https://vk.com/dev/errors

> 2 Приложение выключено.
>   Необходимо включить приложение в настройках `https://vk.com/editapp?id={Ваш API_ID}` или использовать тестовый режим (`test_mode=1`)

**EDIT:**

Раз вы так уверены, что у вас всё правильно с приложением и настройками, то следующая мысль:

Какой у вас размер mp3 файла?

ВК сделан на php, и там есть определенные лимиты на размеры загружаемых файлов. Ошибка с кодом 2 при загрузке файлов в php означает что превышен такой лимит на размер файла.

http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php

**EDIT**:

Можно проверить сам файл, загрузить другой. Проблема может быть в кодеках.

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос до конца, в том числе постскриптум.

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос какой запрос вы отправляете в api.getAudioUploadServer();

Comment: мой вопрос содержит всю необходимую информацию. Я же написал, что использую API от создателя Kate, он же thest1 на гитхабе. В исходном коде API написано как осуществляется запрос, достаточно в поле для поиска внутри репозитория ввести эту функцию

Comment: Если вы используете код из гитхаба то вы пользуетесь API версии 5.5. Текущая версию 5.30 <-- разница в 25 версий.

Comment: Изменение не дало других результатов

Comment: Какой у вас размер файла?

Comment: размер файла 127кб

Comment: Попробуйте сделать название файла меньше, и без подчеркиваний и прочих символов.

Comment: пробовал, называл vhvh.mp3 и тот же результат

Comment: Хорошо, попробуйте загрузить файл с компьютера - по той же ссылке. Если не сработает - ждите ответа техподдержки, так как можно гадать до бесконечности.

Comment: Хм, а может дело в кодеках - то есть в самом вашем файле? попробуйте отправлять другие mp3 файлы.

Comment: Попробовали с другим mp3?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Проблема была в кодеке аудио файла, после использования Lame все заработало

Comment: Понятно. Действительно, чтобы ВК проиграл ваше аудио, нужно чтобы оно было в поддерживаемом формате, включая кодеки.

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае решение было в том, что я неправильно отсылал файл. В картинках можно было отсылать переменную `file1`, а в аудио не прокатило (присылалось именно `%7B%22error%22%3A-2%7D`) и заработало только после того как назвал переменную для файла как в доках - `file`